# PHP - & in header()

Tags: php, redirect, parameters, header, ampersand

I have the parameter:

```
http://example.com?ex=http://la.net?c1=a1&c2=a2&c3=a3
```

I want to redirect to this URL, but while I do it, I'm getting into

```
http://example.com?ex=http://la.net?c1=a1
```

I know that it's because of the `&` sign...

Comment: How does the corresponding code look like?

Comment: with header('Location: $URL ');

Answer (score 5):

You should encode parameters that is passed to URL:

```
$url = "http://example.com?ex=".urlencode("http://la.net?c1=a1&c2=a2&c3=a3");
header('Location: '.$url);
```

Comment: What if the URL had another parameter? That wouldn’t fix the problem as described.

Comment: @Gumbo What do you mean by another parameter?

Comment: What if the URL would have another parameter apart from *ex* like `http://example.com?ex=…&foo=bar`? Escaping the URL parameter value is right, but that doesn’t fix the issue that the resulting URL may contain a plain `&` like `http://example.com?ex=http%3A%2F%2Fla.net%3Fc1%3Da1%26c2%3Da2%26c3%3Da3&foo=bar` does.

Comment: I'm trying it on FB logout (PHP SDK) but it's not redirecting the right page so it seems that it's not working. Maybe there a specific syntax for passing of parameters in FB ?

Comment: @Nimi Please update and explain your question clearly, we are not predictor here.

Comment: @Gumbo What is wrong with that, I don't understand your question. If you have additional parameter, you can simply concatenate it to the URL without encoding it: `$url = "http://example.com?ex=".urlencode("http://la.net?c1=a1&c2=a2&c3=a3")."&foo=bar";`

Comment: @Emre Yazıcı: According to Nimi’s description, the `&` isn’t handled correctly somehow. Now you suggest to encode the whole query (or everything that is following the first `=`). Besides the doubt, whether this is even equivalent to what was intended with the original URL (three parameters: `ex=http://la.net?c1=a1`, `c2=a2`, and `c3=a3`?), this doesn’t fix the initial problem where a `&` isn’t handled correctly if there actually is another parameter.

Comment: @Gumbo Yes, the situation (and question) is ambiguous. I assumed whole query string after `la.net` belongs to `la.net` and suggested encoding whole query string. If a key value pair, for example `c3=a3`, belongs to `example.com`, then `c3=a3` should not be encoded as I wrote the comment above. It's up to user's intention to decide, it's hard to tell which URL `c2` and `c3` keys belonging to.

Comment: I will be more specific. Here is the full url: https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next="http://www.la.net/in.php?id=98&thoiu=21214&access_token=32323329u93840hjfw0few" . While there is a redirecting I'm getting the page "http://www.la.net/in.php?id=98" and there are missing parameter - thoiu and access_token

Comment: @Nimi There shouldn't be difference in essence. Also you haven't mention about using Facebook API, please update your question (not here) and add some **real** code.

Answer (score 1):

you should just be able to do something like this:

```
header('Location: http://example.com?ex=' . urlencode($_GET['ex']));
```

[urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) takes a string and changes the characters in a way where the string can then be passed as a value within an url so that it does not effect the entire url.

Comment: I'm trying it on FB logout (PHP SDK) but it's not redirecting the right page so it seems that it's not working. Maybe there a specific syntax for passing of parameters in FB ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `&amp;` instead of `&` in the parameter value.

```
function fixURL($curURL){
   return preg_replace("/&/","&amp;",$curURL);
}
$param1 = "http://la.net?c1=a1&c2=a2&c3=a3";
$param2 = "http://la.net?c1=a1";
$param3 = "http://ladelala.net?c1=a1&c2=a2&c3=a3";
$url = "http://example.com?ex=".fixURL($param1) . "&ex2=".fixURL($param2) . "&ex3=".fixURL($param3);
header('Location: '.$url);
```